# Definite article before place name

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Sometimes people say:

> I am going to visit the Taj Mahal.

But sometimes:

> I am going to visit Taj Mahal.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

The definite article becomes confusing to me at times. Could you please help me how it is used in general?

Comment: As you know when they say "the Taj Mahal" it means the world monument. We also see that the name "Taj Mahal" is used for many hotels, home. So i would guess the second sentence would be something related to these kind.

Comment: The second variant would never sound acceptable to my ears. Unless there is a town. state or person of that name (Taj Mahal).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You are right. The second expression is not correct. Thank you :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If a restaurant were called Taj Mahal, someone might well say "We're going to eat at Taj Mahal", but when speaking about "the" Taj Mahal, you would always use "the".

Comment: @HostileFork If a restaurant were called 'Ritz', someone might well say "We're going to eat at Ritz". It would not sound acceptable to my ears.